# remove noise in the image - Python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, scikit-image

I am trying to do removing the noise in this image using cv2 Python:

[image]

I used

```
img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)

img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((2,2),np.uint8))
```

but the result is not correct,

how to reduce the noise to make the image more visible?

Comment: What do you consider "noise"? That input image is very low quality, I, a human, can't even read the text.

Comment: @stateMachine, yes, thats the best I get from the web camera, how should we get teh visible image, how to approach, thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not a noise but blur. What you can do in this case is listed below. However, I believe that they will not work in your case. Since your input image is really in low resolution, "garbage-in garbage-out" principle works. Even so you may give a chance to these algorithms.

1. **Wiener filter:** which is a very useful to recover an image. [Here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/d3c/tutorial_out_of_focus_deblur_filter.html) is a useful example to implement. You may have a look at [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dfd/tutorial_motion_deblur_filter.html) also.
2. Get a higher resolution input.